# Finding height to go around Loop De Loop?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I am rolling a small ball down a track with a Loop De Loop, and I want to know the minimum height required for it to go all the way around it without actually doing it experimentally. I know that the kinetic energy at the top is 
$KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $, and that Work = $(KE_f)-(KE_i)$, which boils down to:
$mgh = \frac{1}{2}mv_f^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_i^2$. So using this information, how would I solve for height, when we don't know what $v_f$ or $v_i$ would be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to solve for the speed at the top of the loop, which you can do without using conservation of energy. Use the fact that the loop is a circle, and that at the top of the loop, gravity is the only force that keeps the ball moving in a circle. That will allow you to find the speed.

If you want a very exact answer, you'll also need to account for the fact that some energy goes into the *rotation* of the ball, not just its motion along the track. If the ball is very small, this rotational energy will not be much, but if the ball is not that small, it may make a significant difference in your result.